# "Photo field" in "article_table" or independent table for photo?

Tags: database-design

I have a table for articles with several fields ,each article can have  photo/photos ,is it good that have a field for photo in article_table or i make another table for photo/photos and why?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention "photos" plural, I'll assume you can have multiple photos per article.

In that case, you'd want an association table.

Something like:

```
ARTICLE
--------------
ID(pk)    NUMBER NOT NULL,
AUTHOR_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
TITLE     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
CONTENT   CLOB NOT NULL

ARTICLE_PHOTO
-----------------
ARTICLE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
PHOTO_ID NUMBER NOT NULL

(ARTICLE_ID, PHOTO_ID) is the PK, and both ARTICLE_ID and PHOTO_ID are FKs

PHOTO
--------------------
ID(pk) NUMBER NOT NULL,
PHOTO  BLOB NOT NULL
```

Comment: yes but as i wrot photo/photos may be an article have no photo and another have several photos therefore can i use your design for this condition?

Comment: and ARTICLE_PHOTO is needed? can't i put  ID(pk) of photo table as a FK in ARTICLE table?

Comment: for photo field i put the name of file and if an article has several photos i want that separate them with(,) in its culumn is this ok?

Comment: Yes, you can use this design for the condition of having either no photos with an article or several.  Yes, the association table ARTICLE_PHOTO is needed.  If you just put the PHOTO ID into the ARTICLE TABLE, you can only have one photo per article, unless you're going to have multiple rows for a single article in the ARTICLE table.

Comment: "article has several photos i want that separate them with(,) in its culumn is this ok?" - No, that's not OK at all.  That's very poor database design.

This article should help:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

Comment: thanks,i read that article and very helpfull,but suppose that i put 2 fileds in article table one for one main photo that i put only one photo and the other for if there are some other photos for that article and in that field i separate with comma,do you think that this is not ok?

Comment: thanks , just somebody and Wade Williams
,yes i thought maybe at first we think that it is difficult but at the later it will be simple.

Comment: It's not so much a matter of simple versus complex.  Poor database design leads to inconsistent data.  For example, what if in your method, someone put a comma with no second photo after it?  Or what if they put the same photo twice?  There's just no way to ensure valid data with that design.

Answer (score 0):

if it's always exactly one image, then it's a matter of design.  if the count can vary, then you must put it in a separate table, because otherwise you're in for trouble querying and updating the data.

Comment: yes it can be vary,one article have no photo and another maybe have 6 photos

Answer (score 0):

Consider this -- each article can have many photos, each photo can appear in many articles.

[image: articlewphoto_model_01]

Comment: Just curious, what tool is used to draw this?